# How do I add V2 Active Directory authentication w/Client Secrets to an Azure Web App within its ARM template file?

Tags: azure, azure-webapps

Currently have an ARM template (JSON) that's used to deploy a web app w/authentication (AD, w/Microsoft as the authentication provider...

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": ""
        },
        "webApp": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "JOIN-Web"
        },
        "serviceApp": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "JOIN-Service"
        },
        "runtimeStack": {
            "type": "object",
            "defaultValue": {
                "stack": "dotnetcore",
                "dotnetVersion": "v6.0"
            }
        },
        "sku": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "F1"
        },
        "db": {
            "type": "object",
            "defaultValue": {
                "server": "join-db-server",
                "username": "join-db-server-admin",
                "password": "8gun@deebiE",
                "name": "JOINApps"
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "deploymentName": "[deployment().name]",
        "environmentName": "[if(equals('', parameters('name')), if(contains(variables('deploymentName'), '.'), split(variables('deploymentName'), '.')[1], variables('deploymentName')), parameters('name'))]",
        "appServicePlanName": "[concat('ASP-', variables('environmentName'))]",
        "webAppName": "[format('{0}-{1}', parameters('webApp'), variables('environmentName'))]",
        "serviceAppName": "[format('{0}-{1}', parameters('serviceApp'), variables('environmentName'))]",
        "dbServerName": "[format('{0}-{1}', parameters('db').server, variables('environmentName'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
            "name": "[variables('appServicePlanName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('sku')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
            "name": "[variables('webAppName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "state": "Stopped",
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]",
                "siteConfig": {
                    "metadata": [
                        {
                            "name": "CURRENT_STACK",
                            "value": "[parameters('runtimeStack').stack]"
                        }
                    ],
                    "netFrameworkVersion": "[parameters('runtimeStack').dotnetVersion]",
                    "phpVersion": "",
                    "publicNetworkAccess": "Enabled"
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
            "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
            "name": "[concat(variables('webAppName'), '/', 'authsettingsV2')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "globalValidation": {
                    "redirectToProvider": "azureactivedirectory",
                    "requireAuthentication": true,
                    "unauthenticatedClientAction": "RedirectToLoginPage"    
                },
                "identityProviders": {
                    "azureActiveDirectory": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "isAutoProvisioned": true,
                        "registration": {
                            "clientId": "<clientid>",
                            "clientSecretSettingName": "MICROSOFT_PROVIDER_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET",
                            "openIdIssuer": "https://sts.windows.net/<tenantid>/v2.0"
                        },
                        "validation": {
                            "allowedAudiences": [
                                "api://<clientid>"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "legacyMicrosoftAccount": {
                        "enabled": true
                    }   
                },
                "login": {
                    "allowedExternalRedirectUrls": [],
                    "tokenStore": {
                        "enabled": true
                    }
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('webAppName'))]"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Although the web app is created w/the authentication V2 settings when deploying w/this JSON, it does NOT include the client secret w/the name "MICROSOFT_PROVIDER_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET" bundled in with it--in the Azure Portal, when I examine the list of secrets under identity provider (Microsoft) within the authentication settings for the deploy app, "Client secret setting name" is blank.

What do I need to include in my JSON template file (i. e. under the "Microsoft.Web/sites/config" block) to include that secret name, along w/a secret value for it?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution--template JSON for a single web app w/V2 AD authentication enabled (using a Microsoft ID provider) and a client secret is...

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": ""
        },
        "webApp": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "JOIN-Web"
        },
        "runtimeStack": {
            "type": "object",
            "defaultValue": {
                "stack": "dotnetcore",
                "dotnetVersion": "v6.0"
            }
        },
        "sku": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "F1"
        },
        "webAppClientId": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "<clientId>"   
        },
        "webAppClientSecret": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "<clientSecret>"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "deploymentName": "[deployment().name]",
        "environmentName": "[if(equals('', parameters('name')), if(contains(variables('deploymentName'), '.'), split(variables('deploymentName'), '.')[1], variables('deploymentName')), parameters('name'))]",
        "appServicePlanName": "[concat('ASP-', variables('environmentName'))]",
        "webAppName": "[format('{0}-{1}', parameters('webApp'), variables('environmentName'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
            "name": "[variables('appServicePlanName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('sku')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
            "name": "[variables('webAppName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
"state": "Stopped",
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]",
                "siteConfig": {
                    "appSettings": [
                        {
                            "name": "MICROSOFT_PROVIDER_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET",
                            "value": "[parameters('webAppClientSecret')]"
                        }    
                    ],
                    "metadata": [
                        {
                            "name": "CURRENT_STACK",
                            "value": "[parameters('runtimeStack').stack]"
                        }
                    ],
                    "netFrameworkVersion": "[parameters('runtimeStack').dotnetVersion]",
                    "phpVersion": "",
                    "publicNetworkAccess": "Enabled"
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[variables('appServicePlanName')]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
            "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
            "name": "[concat(variables('webAppName'), '/', 'slotConfigNames')]",
            "properties": {
                "appSettingNames": [
                    "MICROSOFT_PROVIDER_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET"    
                ]
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[variables('webAppName')]"    
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
            "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
            "name": "[concat(variables('webAppName'), '/', 'authsettingsV2')]",
            "properties": {
                "globalValidation": {
                    "redirectToProvider": "azureactivedirectory",
                    "requireAuthentication": true,
                    "unauthenticatedClientAction": "RedirectToLoginPage"    
                },
                "identityProviders": {
                    "azureActiveDirectory": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "isAutoProvisioned": true,
                        "registration": {
                            "clientId": "[parameters('webAppClientId')]",
                            "clientSecretSettingName": "MICROSOFT_PROVIDER_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET",
                            "openIdIssuer": "[concat('https://sts.windows.net/', tenant().tenantId, '/v2.0')]"
                        },
                        "validation": {
                            "allowedAudiences": [
                                "[concat('api://', parameters('webAppClientId'))]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }   
                },
                "login": {
                    "allowedExternalRedirectUrls": [],
                    "tokenStore": {
                        "enabled": true
                    }
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[variables('webAppName')]"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```